# Concatenate/Minify set of files (dynamically) with one static file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm wanting to concatenate and minify a number of files each with the same static file.  Example:

```
src/folder1/my.js
src/folder2/my.js
src/folder3/my.js
```

and concatenate each one of those `my.js` files with one single `folder_global\global.js`, but still call it `my.js` and move them into a build file, so

```
build/folder1/my.js
build/folder2/my.js
build/folder2/my.js
```

And now each of the files include the global.js. I can't seem to get grunt-uglify or grunt-concat to do this exactly, or I'm just not using them correctly.

Here's what I'm trying to do with uglify in the Gruntfile:

```
uglify: {
  newFiles: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '',
      src: ['files/**/my.js', 'folder_global/global.js'],
      dest: 'build/'
    }]
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you share your Gruntfile.js? Seeing it may help folks suggest a solution that won't conflict with other things you are doing. Also list any other tasks that you expect to interact with those files.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I was able to figure it out and it was fairly simple.  This may not be the best way, so please let me know if there's a better way to do.  Thought I'd post it in case it may help someone.  Just required that I use the process option with grunt-contrib-concat:

```
concat: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      process: function(src, filepath) {
        var global1 = 'file/global1.js';
        var global2 = 'file/global2.js';
        var globalSrc = grunt.file.read(global1);
        var readySrc = grunt.file.read(global2);
        return global1.concat(src, global2);
       },
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '',
      src: ['src/**.js'],
      dest: 'build/'
    }],
  },
}
```